# Can exams2moodle export additional metainfo such as idnumber and tags?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

When I export the xml file of a multiple choice question, it contains the following lines:

```
    <idnumber>arbitrary_id_set_by_user</idnumber>
    <answernumbering>ABCD</answernumbering>
    <tag></tag>
```

Is there a way to add `idnumber`, `answernumbering` and `tag` to the metainformation section of the question so that r-exams can export to moodle XML as `<idnumber>idnumber</idnumber>`,`<answernumbering>ABCD</answernumbering>`, `<tag>tag1</tag>`, and `<tag>tag2</tag>` etc?

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I adapted my answer correspondingly.

Comment: Did the modifed answer resolve the question sufficiently? I haven't provided more detail on the idnumber because I still don't understand what this would be needed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<answernumbering>` tag can be set in `exams2moodle()` via the `answernumbering=` argument, see `?exams2moodle`. The reason for this is that this is set in the same way for all exercises in a quiz. This is more consistent than setting it individually and potentially inconsistently in the meta-information of the different exercises.

The `<idnumber>` tag appears to be used by Moodle only for internal purposes. It is also not mentioned in the official Moodle XML documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Moodle_XML_format. Hence we did not implement it in `exams2moodle()`.

The `<tag>` is currently not supported in `exams2moodle()` because we felt that it would be more important to have tags in the Rmd (or Rnw) exercise itself and not the Moodle version of the exercise. For structuring the content on the Moodle side the `exsection` meta-information can be used, see [boxhist](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/boxhist/) for a worked example.

Finally, you can add arbitrary metainformation by using the `exextra` tag. This is used, for example, in the [essayreg](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/essayreg/) exercise template. However, there is no general way of using this extra metainformation to insert additional XML code in the `exams2moodle()` output. To do that, the source code underlying `exams2moodle()` would have to be adapted correspondingly.

Comment: Thank you Achim for your response! I watched all your tutorials on r-exams. They are awesome! As a new user of both r-exams and moodle, my questions may be dumb. But I thought for multiple choise questions, the <idnumber> and <answernumbering> could be a useful add-on for r-exams so that one doesn't have to manually insert question ids and in my case, the options need to be displayed as ABCD instead of abcd (to conform with existing practice).

Comment: The `answernumbering` can be set as an option in `exams2moodle()` as it should not be controlled by the individual exercise but consistently for the quiz. Note that this was not mentioned in your original question! I was just about to modify both your question and my answer - but then didn't because I don't know what the `idnumber` should be. It is not mentioned in the official documentation <https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Moodle_XML_format>. Please modify your question to be more precise about `answernumbering` and `idnumber`. Then I'll update my answer so that it can hopefully be accepted.

Comment: Hello. I think it would be very helpful to be able to set some additional (arbitrary) XML tags. For example, my moodle systems automatically sets `<showstandardinstruction>` to 1. To avoid setting it to 0 by hand for each exercise, it would be helpful being able to do it via a command in the Rmd file or in some other way when generating the exercises. From this answer I understand this is currently not possible, or is it?

Comment: Is this a standard Moodle XML tag? I checked the official documentation at https://docs.moodle.org/403/en/Moodle_XML_format but couldn't find any pointers to it.